# mysql query optimization - indexes

Tags: php, mysql, indexing, latitude-longitude, sql-optimization

I have a database with 3 tables.

```
CREATE TABLE `records` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `nu` varchar(40) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  `name` varchar(128),
  `latitude` float NOT NULL,
 `longitude` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category_label` varchar(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; 

CREATE TABLE `relational` (
  `r_id` int(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`r_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Also I have 2 foreign keys, category_id and id.
I have made index for category_label and latitude too.
I've made my query like this

```
SELECT id, name, latitude, longitude, category_label, ( 6371 * acos( cos( 
radians('$lat') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - 
radians('$lng') ) + sin( radians('$lat') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) 
AS distance, FROM records JOIN relational ON records.id = relational.id
JOIN categories ON relational.category_id = categories.category_id
WHERE category_label = '$label' GROUP BY distance HAVING (distance <= 
'$radius') ORDER BY distance
```

My problem is that I have a big database and it takes too long for the query to run. What indexes should I use for this query. Actually I don't know which is the right way to have indexes that will help me with the distance. Should I change the indexes? How can I improve my db structure or my query? I'm using InnoDB.

Comment: Run `EXPLAIN`on your query and post the result.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should probably take a look at [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-datatypes.html) and [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-spatial-indexes.html) - I highly recommend using it instead of common datatypes in your case.

As far as your current schema goes, consider adding indexes on `relational.id` and `relational.category_id` (2 separate indexes). But it won't help in the long run either. Other thing that will help - do not calculate `distance` on the fly - cache it in another table, for example, where you can index it: one of the most expensive parts of your query is grouping and post-filtering on dynamic (hence, slow) field

And you don't really need another index for `categories.category_label` - you already have UNIQUE constraint on it, which implies indexing.

You can also create covering index on your `records` table, but it won't give much of a boost compared to fixing dynamic field operations

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I' ll check it out. But I want to ask something maybe silly about the first thing you said. I probably can't change my database engine now for this database. But if I could, I've seen that spatial data are supported by MyISAM. But If I use this I can't use foreign keys so I can't connect the columns of my tables. Am I right? So I guess it won't work fine for me.

Comment: @arek I'm afraid you got it wrong, spatial datatypes are not separate database engine, its engine support list can be found here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/creating-spatial-columns.html

Comment: @arek on foreign keys: 1) you don't have to have a foreign key to join tables. Those are used to create constraints 2) Why would you need to create foreign key based on your spatial data? You search and/or calculate over those, but connect to other data via some identification fields, like `category_id` or some such

Comment: @arek and there is not such thing as silly question, but those who don't ask them should be considered silly

Answer (score 0):

1. To help get started in `categories`, add `INDEX(category_label)`
2. `relational` looks like a "many-to-many" mapping.  Are "records" in multiple "categories", and each "category" has many "records"?  If so, then many-to-many is needed.  For improved performance, follow the tips [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) .
3. Then...

The quick-and-easy way to improve a distance search is to have a "bounding box" in the `WHERE` clause and have `INDEX(latitude), INDEX(longitude)`.

If `nu` is `UNIQUE`, then you probably ought to have it be the `PRIMARY KEY` and get rid if `id`.  (Change `Relational` first.)

The next problem is that the filtering (`WHERE`) is reaching into two tables (to filter on category and on location).  Such cannot be optimized.  Instead, the hope is that the query can efficiently filter on one table, then further refine it when looking in the other table.

Answer (score 0):

Google spatial index. It is 2D indexing for geometry data.